# What is the simplest way to serve static content in JBoss 5 from a war file?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, war

I want to deploy static content (html,css,js) to an existing JBoss 5.1 server in a war file.  Is there a simple web.xml I can create that will work for jboss? Are there jboss specific gotchas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the war is only serving static files, web.xml is optional or you can leave the web-app element blank.  The context root will be the same as the war file name by default, and you would need to create a jboss-web.xml file in the WEB-INF directory to change it (so app.war would deploy to http://localhost/app by default).  Directories and files next to WEB-INF in the war directory structure will be made public.
Example jboss-web.xml that only changes the context root

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>mySpecialRoot</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```